# Run script only when file/dir is created/removed

Tags: php, apache, file, directory, cgi

**How to run php script(s) !only! when file or directory is

created/deleted through ftp or via etc cms?**
parallel to js, where you can create real time event listeners 

for information I only have webserver w apache+php
**I don't have permissions to install aditional packages**

I already know about cron, but it runs on interval :S

Answer (score 1):

I would look into [inotify](http://php.net/manual/en/book.inotify.php) as it has the ability to recieve events when files or folders are created/modified/deleted.

Example:

```
$fd = inotify_init();
stream_set_blocking($fd, 0);
inotify_add_watch($fd,'./test/',IN_ALL_EVENTS);

while(true){
        $events = inotify_read($fd);
        if($events){
                print_r($events);
        }
        sleep(1);
}
```